# Spring ConversionService string to map like @Value

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to replicate the spring @Value behavior with spring ConversionService.

So when i have the following @Value annotation, it works fine:

```
@Value(#{${my.property.key:{'defaultKey': 'defaultValue'}}})
private Map<String, String> myMap;
```

For another scenario I have a custom resolver which uses the spring ConversionService:

```
public class SpringConfigProvider implements ConfigProvider {

    private final ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfigProvider(ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory, ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // NOSONAR if using type safe variant type.cast(); then we have to bother Integer to int conversion
    @Override
    public <T> T resolve(String key, Class<T> type) {
        String resolveEmbeddedValue = beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(key);
        return conversionService.convert(resolveEmbeddedValue, type);
    }

}
```

When I call resolve with

```
resolve("${my.property.key:{'defaultKey': 'defaultValue'}}", Map.class);
```

spring throws

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]
```

So the beanFactory resolves the key correctly an returns for example *{'key':'value'}*.
But the conversionService wont convert this string to a Map.

So how or what das **@Value** differently and how can I get the same result manually?

I could add a custom Converter, but spring knows already somewhere how to convert such string to map. I would prefer to use the same way.